# jQuery StickyPanel issue with WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, sticky

I am a intermediate level web designer, and have just reworked a wordpress site creating my own theme.

I've implemented a jQuery StickyPanel to have a top menu bar that stays with the page.  If I have the menu bar placed at margin-top: 1px , it works fine, but obviously I have a pixel of space showing.

If I place the sticky menu at margin-top:0px, it will function properly, but it won't detach when I am at the top of the page again, and won't allow me to scroll to the full 100%.

The site is now live and I have set the margin to 1px as that is a better option of the two, but ideally I need that pixel to go away!

It works fine if I make a test .html page, it is something happening with the WordPress calling of the header.php or something as far as I can tell...but like I said, I am intermediate, and my searching and trial and error has yet to find a solution.

the website is www.therayandthero.com

my css for the sticky panel is

```
#menu {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 1px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 23px;
  padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
    box-shadow: 2px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);}

#menu.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 99%;
  background-color: black;
  color: #e5e6d9;
  z-index: 9999;
  -moz-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
-webkit-box-shadow:1px 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
box-shadow:1px -1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);}
```

my implementation of the code is in the header.php follow, and is as follows:

```
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="menu" class="sticky"> 
<div id="toplogo"><a href="http://www.therayandthero.com"><img     src="http://www.therayandthero.com/wp-content/themes/randrtwopointoh/images/rrsill_off.png"     class="rollover"></a></div>
<div id="toptext"><h1><a href="mailto:therayandthero@gmail.com">CONTACT</a></h1></div>       <div id="toptext2"><h1><a href="#caro">CATEGORIES</a></h1></div>
<div id="search-box"><?php get_search_form(); ?></div> 
</div>
<div id="wrapper"> <!-- wrapper -->
<div id="topad">...
```

I don't know if you need to see more of the code to do this... If so, let me know and I will happily show you what you need.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Stack Overflow is an English-language Q&A site. Please capitalize "I" when referring to yourself. There is never a time where you should write **i** instead of **I**.

Answer (score 0):

Your website is not valide :
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.therayandthero.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.2

This is not a problem, but if some tag are not close, javascript and css can't work.
If you want to find lot of problems, use css/html inspector in webkit or firebug in firefox.